# When I am accessing server using ssh key .I got the "Permission Denied Please Try again."

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

What I have done till now

---

1-SSH KEY Generated from my hosting cpanel.
i.e now showing under .ssh folder of user's root.
2-SSH KEY authorised from my hosting cpanel.
3-Now I have download the private key ppk file i.e id_rsa.ppk and put it to the my local machine.
4-Now when I access server using ssh -i path to key user@host after enter It is prompt for passphrase for 3 times I am using my passphrases and after that It is prompt for password ,after inserting the password then I am getting Permission Denied Please Try again.After inserting the password 3 times .I am getting `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`
.

Comment: Do you have WHM access to that server or just cPanel access?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @Bogdan Stoica No I am using cpanel access,@Martin Prikryl I have moved it on Super User http://superuser.com/questions/1178231/when-i-am-accessing-server-using-ssh-key-i-got-the-permission-denied-please-tr

Comment: So please delete this copy.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the sshd_config file, if you have used AllowUsers , it might be the reason.